# How can I use a variable inside one or multiple hotkeys?

Tags: windows, scripting, autohotkey, hotkeys

(Very new to AHK, so sorry if this sounds very stupid/trivial)

I have a small AHK script (see below) with a variable called `var`. I would like to call and modify this variable from within multiple hotkeys. However, even when trying to "yield" its value (with the `F8` hotkey) the value doesn't get printed. How can I go about with this?

```
#SingleInstance, force
+Escape::ExitApp
!r::Reload
!p::Suspend

var := 42

F8::
  MsgBox % "Var value is " . var . "."
Return

;F12::
;blabla not relevant yet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable declaration is unreachable code.
The code execution stops when the first hotkey label is encountered. This is called the [Auto-execute Section](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto).

Move your hotkey definition to be at the very bottom.
(All hotkeys defined by hotkey labels always get created regardless of being in the auto-execute section or not)

And as a bonus, the concatenation operator `.` is redundant, you don't need to use it, you can just leave it out.
(Unless you prefer to use it, of course)